# Why is the "results" parameter in the GCM downstream HTTP message response json marked as optional?

Tags: android, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

According to this https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table5 the results parameter is set as optional, but as far as i have understood it would at least contain an object with an error. Is there an instance i have not yet noticed where it would not be a part of the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when 401s are thrown by the server. In that case, the response is in HTML format. You can examine this by running the following curl command without changing the API key:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=Some_Unauthorized_API_Key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

Comment: As far as i can see this case would return without any JSON at all. I am thinking about the instance where it returns JSON and there is no results parameter in it.